# Adding onPressed or onTab to BubbleBottomBarItem in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, floating-action-button, bottomnavigationview

Been trying to solve this all day.
I am basically new to flutter.
I want the Bottom icon buttons to have its own onTap methods like the normal FAB or BottomNavigationBar. please help! Thank you

Here is the code.

```
    return BubbleBottomBar(
      hasNotch: true,
      opacity: .2,
      currentIndex: currentIndex,
      onTap: changePage,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
          top: Radius.circular(
              16)), 
      elevation: 8,
      items: <BubbleBottomBarItem>[
        BubbleBottomBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              color: Colors.indigo,
            ),
            title: Text("Home")),
        BubbleBottomBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.folder_open,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.folder_open,
              color: Colors.indigo,
            ),
            title: Text("Get Job")),
        BubbleBottomBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.add_circle_outline,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.add_circle_outline,
              color: Colors.indigo,
            ),
            title: Text("Add Job")),
      ],
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BubbleBottomBarItem` does not have any `onTap` or `onPressed` method, hence you need to use `onTap` in `BubbleBottomBar`. You can implement `changePage` as given in below example to handle the `onTap` in `BubbleBottomBar`.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int currentIndex;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    currentIndex = 0;
  }

  void changePage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
    });

    //You can have a switch case to Navigate to different pages
    switch (currentIndex){
      case 0:
         Navigator.push( context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AnyClass()),
         );
         break;
     ...
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BubbleBottomBar(
        hasNotch: true,
        fabLocation: BubbleBottomBarFabLocation.end,
        opacity: .2,
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: changePage,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
            top: Radius.circular(
                16)), 
        elevation: 8,
        items: <BubbleBottomBarItem>[
        ...
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so how do I add this onTap myself been finding it difficult please i need help.

Comment: I mean how do i add the Page Navigation for example (  onTap: (){Navigator.of(context).pushName('/Add Job')},

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can use a switch case to navigate to different pages.

Comment: Now the only issue I am having now is I created a separate .dart file for the BubbleBottomBar that is (bubblebottombar.dart). so all pages(tap menu) could be called from it. This works well just that only the switched case is changed and not the current page so the icons button of the BubbleBottomBar is never changed always on the home page. since the currentIndex is set to 0 that is the home page. my question is how do I manage to make the currentIndex change?